# Failed to copy Hadoop and Java packages to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-hadoop

I am trying to setup a Hadoop cluster on Google Compute Engine, and I have been following [these instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop). Everything seems to have worked just fine until I ran:

```
./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py setup <project ID> <bucket name>
```

with my project ID and bucket name I created. The script does not seem to have access to something and crashes with a 403; here is the tail end of the output with the error messages:

```
Uploading   ...kages/ca-certificates-java_20121112+nmu2_all.deb: 14.57 KB/14.57 KB    
Uploading   ...duce/tmp/deb_packages/libnspr4_4.9.2-1_amd64.deb: 316 B/316 B    
Uploading   ...e/tmp/deb_packages/libnss3-1d_3.14.3-1_amd64.deb: 318 B/318 B    
Uploading   ...dk-6-jre-headless_6b27-1.12.6-1~deb7u1_amd64.deb: 366 B/366 B    
Uploading   ...duce/tmp/deb_packages/libnss3_3.14.3-1_amd64.deb: 315 B/315 B    
ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Forbidden
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Forbidden
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
CommandException: 7 files/objects could not be transferred.

########## ERROR ##########
Failed to copy Hadoop and Java packages to Cloud Storage gs://<bucket name>/mapreduce/tmp/
###########################

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 226, in main
    ComputeClusterForHadoop().ParseArgumentsAndExecute(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 222, in ParseArgumentsAndExecute
    params.handler(params)
  File "./compute_cluster_for_hadoop.py", line 36, in SetUp
    gce_cluster.GceCluster(flags).EnvironmentSetUp()
  File "/Path/To/solutions-google-compute-engine-cluster-for-hadoop/gce_cluster.py", line 149, in EnvironmentSetUp
    raise EnvironmentSetUpError('Environment set up failed.')
gce_cluster.EnvironmentSetUpError: Environment set up failed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you switch to using the more updated, live and maintained "bdutil" package by Google. You can find the details in the [GCP Hadoop announcement forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gcp-hadoop-announce).

If you go to the most updated announcement, you will find a link to the most updated "bdutil" package (currently 0.36.4). It will simplify your cluster deployment, and support both Hadoop and Spark clusters.

Also, I would like to recommend:

1. Deploy the cluster from within a machine in GCE. It will make the process more speedy and reliable.
2. In the file `bdutil_env.sh`, change the parameter `GCUTIL_SLEEP_TIME_BETWEEN_ASYNC_CALLS_SECONDS` from 0.1 to 0.5 (for me, it fixed recurring deployment errors)